# ASP.NET MVC Pass mutiple params from getJson to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am making a call to a controller action in javascript using the getJson method.  I need to pass two parameters to my action method on the controller, but I am struggling to do so.  I do not  fully understand the routing tables and not sure if this is what I need to use to get this working.  Please see example below of what I am trying to do.

```
var action = "<%=Url.Content('~/Postcode/GetAddressResults/')%>" + $get("Premise").value + "/" + $get("SearchPostcode").value
$.getJSON(action, null, function(data) {
  $("#AddressDropDown").fillSelect(data);
});
```

This is my route which I don't understand how to make use of...

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "postcode",
 "Postcode/GetAddressResults/{premise}/{postcode}",
 new {
  controller = "Motor", action = "GetAddressResults",
    premise = "", postcode = ""
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely on the right path, though I would need to see your controller to know for sure.  It would need to look something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAddressResults(string premise, string postcode)
{
  //Do something.
  return Json(AddressService.GetResultsOfSomeKind(premise, postcode);
}
```

Set a breakpoint on your ActionResult so you know it's being called.  If it's not, use Firefox and check the Error Console for syntax errors (the code you posted has some).

UPDATE:

What is

```
$get("Premise").value?
```

To get an input's value via jQuery, use:

```
$("#fieldid").val();
```

I recommend using the Firebug plugin for Firefox.  That way you'll know exactly at which point your javascript is breaking.  Most likely you'll find that your "var action =" statement is not properly appending the form field values on the client side before the $.getJSON call sends a request to your controller.